# IntelliJ does not compile/recognize new code

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, intellij-idea, ide

I'm currently developing an `Android` app using `IntelliJ` but since recently `IntelliJ` has not recognized new code when it is compiled and run on a device `(HTC Desire 530)`. I have tested this by `logging/sysouting` and confirming that the new output is not shown in logcat.

The only solution I have found so far is to do `Invalidate Caches / Restart` and then the log output/print appears and the new code is compiled.

If it is of interest I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04` and `IntelliJ 2016.2`.

I have not found any other posts about this so I'm wondering if anybody have has experienced the same?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Android Studio ?

Comment: No, I'm using IntelliJ but Android Studio is based on it so a solution should work for both platforms!

Comment: @badledoge you mean watching is not running properly??